# MySQLのストアドプロシージャ内で呼ばれたselect文の結果を、ストアド内で受取る方法

Tags: mysql

ストアドプロシージャ(A)から他のストアドプロシージャ(B)を呼び出し、
(B)内で呼び出したselect文の結果を、(A)内で受取りたいと考えています。
そもそもこれは可能なのでしょうか。

(B)を修正せずに、対応する方法((A)の書き方)を教えてください。

(B)は他社提供のプロシージャで変更できないような場合を想定してください。

具体的には、次のようなプロシージャ(B)があり、

```sql
delimiter $
create procedure proc_B()
begin
    declare value int;
     /*(省略)*/
    select value;
end$
delimiter ;
```

このプロシージャを別のプロシージャ(A)から呼び出し、上記の変数valueの値を受取りたい。

```sql
delimiter $
create procedure proc_A()
begin
    declare value int;

    /* 呼び出すだけなら、これで良い。*/
    /* ただし(A)の呼び出し元へ直接select結果が戻される。 */
    call proc_B;

    /* 通常のカーソルの様にに宣言するとsyntaxエラーになる */
    declare cur cursor for proc_B;

    /* これもsyntaxエラー。 */
    /* またこれでは複数行返るパターンに対応できない。 */
    call proc_B into value; 

end$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

[本家SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11000907/4037) にこんな答えがありました。

呼ばれる側のプロシージャに OUT パラメータを付けて、

```
CREATE PROCEDURE innerproc(OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
   insert into sometable;
   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into param1 ;
END
```

と定義すれば、

```
CREATE PROCEDURE outerproc()
BEGIN
    CALL innerproc(@a);
    SELECT @a INTO variableinouterproc FROM dual;
END
```

と書くことによって、`@a` に `innerproc` の結果が入るようです。

Comment: 説明が足りませんでしたが、呼ばれる側の修正はしない（できない）前提での呼び出し方法が知りたいのです。

Answer (score 1):

> 通常のカーソルの様にに宣言するとsyntaxエラーになる

もし、カーソルのように複数行を扱いたいのであればですが、MySQL のサーバサイドカーソルは実質テンポラリテーブルのようなものだと聞いたことがあります。

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursor-restrictions.html

だったら、いっそのことテンポラリテーブルを使ってしまってもいいんじゃないかと思います。

```
delimiter $

create procedure proc_B()
begin
    /* 結果を返すためのテンポラリテーブル */
    drop table if exists proc_B__result;
    create temporary table proc_B__result as
        select 1 union all select 2;
end$

create procedure proc_A()
begin
    declare value int;

    /* テンポラリテーブルを走査するカーソル */
    declare cur cursor for select * from proc_B__result;

    /* プロシージャを実行して結果をテンポラリテーブルに挿入 */
    call proc_B();

    /* カーソルを開いて複数行の結果を fetch してみる */
    open cur;
    fetch cur into value;
    fetch cur into value;
    close cur;
end$

delimiter ;

call proc_A();
```

Comment: あ、proc_B の方は修正せずにでしたか・・・